# customized progress bar but with image

Tags: ios, progress-bar

well don't rush and down vote me it's not the usual adding a an image into a progress bar. what i want is to be abel to present (let's say) a circle with star picture but it should be a bit grayed out. the progress should be seen coming from the bottom of the picture and going upwards. as the progress bar progresses, the graying out should start going away gradually. here is a picture of what i mean:

First pic: The progress didn't start yet. thus it's grayed out.

Second pic: The progress started and the picture is being revealed

[image: The progress didn't start yet. thus it's grayed out.]

[image: The progress started and the picture is being revealed]

hope that i made it clear. now what i'm expecting is hint, documentation reference, or tell me what frameworks should be used to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Start with the [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066).

Comment: i know quartz 2D! should i overlap the image needed with it and alter the quartz view to shrink?

Answer (score 0):

One really simple way to do this would be to create a custom view class. This custom view would have an image view showing the full, bright image. This custom view would also add, over the image view, a `UIView` with a semi-transparent black background color. Based on the amount of progress, this cover view's frame can be adjusted to reveal the image below it.

Comment: was thinking that, too, but (a) the mask would need to be the same shape (round) as the icon being covered, and (b) not sure if the OP really wants the meniscus effect at the top edge, but that would require extra work.

Comment: Granted, I glossed over the rounding of the shading but that shouldn't be hard to do with a custom `drawRect:` method in the "shade" view.

Comment: guys do you think tinkering with the UIImageView layer would help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need two images: the round bright star, and a semi-transparent gray one the same shape and size.  Place the gray on top of the star with the same frame.  Make sure that the gray image's contentMode = `UIViewContentModeTopLeft`.  Then as @rmaddy suggests, change the frame (height) of the gray image according to the progress of the activity.

```
CGRectMake(kX, kY, kWidth, kHeight * pctProgress)
```

The "meniscus" effect at the edges is a little trickier.  How badly do you want that?